# mysql php show 10 results from database

Tags: mysql, database

I want display data from mysql database like [Youtube][1] comment 10 comments 'show more 10' link ... how I can get this ?

That is my code

$entities = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `username`, `message` FROM `comments` WHERE `page_name` = '$message_page' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");

```
        if (mysql_num_rows($entities) ==0) {
            echo '<strong>No comment, yet.</strong>';
            } else {
        while ($entities_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($entities)) {
        $entities_timestamp = $entities_row['timestamp'];
        $entities_username = $entities_row['username'];
        $entities_message = $entities_row['message'];
```

}

Comment: What tube have tube you tube tried tube so tube far tube?

Comment: I have to comments box and I will show all them 10 results and contunie more results 10 comments when click more results like youtube . And I don't wonna use pagination just continue down with more 10 results comments from my mysql database....

Comment: I have my php comment box

Comment: Then show us your code please so we can help

Comment: This is pagination, may it be virtual one and with no possibility to scroll through pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What query are you trying ?What have achieved so far?Mention it and it would be easy for others to help you!
As far as your question goes,you will have to use `limit` in your SQL query and on click of **show more** will need to get the next batch of records using ajax

```
   "select * from table_name where (your condition) limit ".$offset.",".$limit.""
```

Here,offset would be the starting point and limit would be the no of records to get.
So,your offset first time would be 0 and limit would be 10.
Next iteration(on clicking **show more**) it will be 10,10
next 20,10 and so on

your jquery function would look like this

```
    $("#idOfShowMore").live('click',function({               
      $.ajax({
        url: "php file with query to database",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"limit":"limit is 10 in your case"},
        dataType : "text",
        success: function(returnData){
            //append the return data on success
        }
       });
     })
```

Hope it helps :)
**Update**
    `SELECT timestamp, username, message FROM comments WHERE page_name = '$message_page' ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 0,10`
 Here,**0 is the offset and 10 is the limit**.This will get the first 10 records of returned by the query.Now you will have to increment your offset by the value of the limit,so do it like-->`offset = offset+limit;`(initialize offset to 0 first)
Now next iteration your offset would be 10 and limit will remain 10 as you need to get 10 records at a time.Call the ajax function on click of your show more link.This should be it.

Comment: $entities = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `username`, `message` FROM `comments` WHERE `page_name` = '$message_page' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
   
   if (mysql_num_rows($entities) ==0) {
    echo '<strong>No comment, yet.</strong>';
    } else {
   while ($entities_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($entities)) {
   $entities_timestamp = $entities_row['timestamp'];
   $entities_username = $entities_row['username'];
   $entities_message = $entities_row['message'];}

Comment: How I can do it with my query can you help me please?

Comment: I can't undestand jquery maaan my page is userdownload.php... Can you help little more. $limit = 10;
   $offset = $offset + $limit;
   
  $entities = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp`, `username`, `message` FROM `comments` WHERE `page_name` = '$message_page' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . $limit . "");

Comment: is it possible we do it only with php and mysql database?

Comment: @user1929805 It won't be good to do it with PHP,bcoz then your page would refresh on each request and entire data has to be brought back from database.Ajax helps you to refresh only a certain part of the page,hence its better you use it.

Comment: I will update an answer after some time.With ajax and php for your query

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting forrrr.

Comment: Get the basics right first!!Add the latest `jquery.js` in your head tag using `<script src"jquery.js"></script>`Then write the ajax function as I mentioned on the `class` or `id` of the show more link that you have.The php file to which you submit the request will have the query that fetches the records on click of show more button.Just have this in place

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/spsb2v3zfr5nvrm/demo_showMoreLink.rar I have created a demo for this,refer it and work on the same lines to complete yours

Comment: Yeaah thank youu sooo much you are the king mannnnn. One sunny day, I'll buy you cold bourbon my friend I precise that ... thanks

Comment: There is a **check mark** beside the answer below **upvote-downvote** buttons which you can check to mark it as accepted!!It will turn to green! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is paginating.
Suppose your comments table is `comm_tb` with the fields `comm_id` etc.
Create an additional search table with one field `comm_id`, named `old_comm`
What you do, in repeated way, is to select the first 10 comments but not those already selected:

`select * from comm_tb ct where not exists (select 1 from old_comm oc where oc.comm_id = ct.comm_id) and rownum <= 10;`

When you have all the 10 records, you perform a batch insert into the `old_comm` table with the ids of the comments already displayed.

In a multiuser environment, extend the `old_comm` table with `user` and consider it when loading the comments.